# Retrieve data Firebase from DateTime node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from `Firebase` but my problem is that one of the node is date for each day and I don't know how to get inside of it.

That's my `JSON` :

```
{
"jsonData": {
    "11-30-2017": {
      "Clau": {
        "-L-BmanPPTqqXxOivGZs": [
          {
            "cantitate": "18",
            "pret": "140",
            "produs": "Camasa",
            "produsId": "-L-BjnaA-Uizg9mI7J3l",
            "qty": 2,
            "subTotal": 280
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get objects inside of the `jsonData` (**cantitate,pret,produsID etc.**). I don't know how to get inside, that's all what I've tried.

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("jsonData")
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: No, it's impossible, too hard

Answer (score 1):

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("jsonData").child("11-30-2017").child("Clau").child("-L-BmanPPTqqXxOivGZs");  
mDatabaseReference .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.wtf(TAG, "onDataChange:Daylog "+dataSnapshot.toString() );
                //your data


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                  //error code
            }

        });
```

Comment: i tried that, not working I want something functionally for each day

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase API only allows you to filter children one level deep (or [with a known path](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)) with its `orderByChild` and `equalTo` methods.

You read through [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) doc to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create dao class to easy manage data .

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Datas {
    public String cantitate;
    public String pret;
    public String produs;
    public String produsId;
    public String qty;

    public Datas() {}
    public Datas(String cantitate, String pret, String produs, String produsId, String qty, String subTotal) {
        this.cantitate = cantitate;
        this.pret = pret;
        this.produs = produs;
        this.produsId = produsId;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }

    public String subTotal;

    public String getCantitate() {
        return cantitate;
    }

    public void setCantitate(String cantitate) {
        this.cantitate = cantitate;
    }

    public String getPret() {
        return pret;
    }

    public void setPret(String pret) {
        this.pret = pret;
    }

    public String getProdus() {
        return produs;
    }

    public void setProdus(String produs) {
        this.produs = produs;
    }

    public String getProdusId() {
        return produsId;
    }

    public void setProdusId(String produsId) {
        this.produsId = produsId;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getSubTotal() {
        return subTotal;
    }

    public void setSubTotal(String subTotal) {
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }

}
```

when you insert data into firebase then you getUnique key L-BmanPPTqqXxOivGZs

```
      mDatabaseReference.child("-L-BmanPPTqqXxOivGZs").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Datas datas = dataSnapshot.getValue(Datas.class);
           //now you have evry thing in yor pojo

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

After data is get then store inside the adapter as follows this is adapter class..

```
class ListAdapters extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            public ListAdapters(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            private List<String> items;

            public ListAdapters(Context context, int resource, List<String> items) {

                super(context, resource, items);

                this.items = items;

            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = convertView;

                if (v == null) {

                    LayoutInflater vi;
                    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                }

                String p = items.get(position);

                if (p != null) {

                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textviewid);


                    if (tt != null) {
                        tt.setText(p);
                    }

                }

                return v;

            }
         }
```

Follow code
Add in to your class
where we get Data

```
List<String> DataAdapter=new ArrayList<String>();
DataAdapter.add(Datas.getCantitate());
DataAdapter.add(Datas.getPret());
DataAdapter.add(Datas.getProdus());
DataAdapter.add(Datas.getProdusId());
DataAdapter.add(Datas.getQty());
    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, DataAdapter);

    ListView DataList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    DataList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks, and how can i display the data, with setText is ok ?

Comment: or is there a better option ? cause i want to display data in a listview

Comment: if you have done with previous then you can set data into listview then i m update my code wait....